# Why does this OCaml functor not recognize the structure type?

Tags: types, ocaml

I've written the following functor and instance,

```
module type Set = sig
  type elt
  type t
  val empty : t
  val insert : elt -> t -> t
  val find : elt -> t -> bool
end

module type OrderedSet = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end

module BstSet(M: OrderedSet) : Set = struct
  type elt = M.t
  type t = M.t tree
  let empty = Leaf
  let rec insert x tr = match tr with
    | Leaf -> Node(Leaf, x, Leaf)
    | Node (lt, y, rt) -> let c = M.compare x y in
                          if c < 0 then Node (insert x lt, y, rt)
                          else if c > 0 then Node (lt, y, insert x rt)
                          else Node (lt, y, rt)
  let rec find x tr = match tr with
    | Leaf -> false
    | Node (lt, y, rt) -> let c = M.compare x y in
                          if c = 0 then true
                          else if c < 0 then find x lt
                          else find x rt
end

module MyString : OrderedSet = struct
  type t = string
  let compare s1 s2 = compare s1 s2
end

module StringSet = BstSet(MyString);;

StringSet.empty |> StringSet.insert "abc";;
```

and the compiler raises the error

```
StringSet.empty |> StringSet.insert "abc";;
                                          ^^^^^
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
         StringSet.elt = BstSet(MyString).elt
Command exited with code 2.
```

This confuses me because I would have thought that something like this would be going on in the compiler:

1. We construct `BstSet(MyString)` with the functor, so that the argument `M` is `MyString`.
2. That means when we call `M.t` this is `string`.
3. That means `elt` is `string`.
4. That means, in the signature for `insert`, we have a function `string -> string tree -> string tree`.

So this should compile.  Or put more directly, I would have thought `StringSet.elt` would be equal to `string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition

```
module BstSet(M: OrderedSet) : Set = struct ... end
```

says nothing about the equality between  `Set.elt` and `M.t` (indeed, they are not required to be the same, e.g., the implementation could embed extra information into the elt type). To express this equality you have to add the [sharing constraint](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/functors.html), e.g.,

```
module BstSet(M: OrderedSet) : Set with type elt = M.t = struct ... end
```

alternatively, you can remove the module type and let the compiler to look into the implementation, e.g., like this

```
module BstSet(M: OrderedSet) = struct ... end
```

This is useful when you're not going to export your functor from your module and are using it for internal purposes only.